# ERROR: column "user1" does not exist, occuring on inserting into postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

Postgres noob, sorry.

The table definition is -

```
create table customer(customerid serial primary key,username varchar(32) not null,fname varchar(32) not null,lname varchar(32) not null,street1 varchar(100),street2 varchar(100),city varchar(100),state varchar(2),zip varchar(5));
```

The insert statement giving the error -

```
insert into customer (username,fname,lname,street1,street2,city,state,zip) values ("user1","fname1","lname1","street1","street2","city","ST","12345");
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes. Double quotes stand for column identifier in Postgres, while single quotes define string literals. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As GMB said, it is about using single quotes. Also I advice you to use SEQUENCE for your primary key than using searial. Little longer to create, easier to manage later.